# Symbol boost could not be resolved

Tags: c++, eclipse, boost

I am using boost and eclipse as my IDE.

Boost is located in /home/ubuntu/cpp/boost_1_52_0/boost

In eclipse IDE I get a red squiggly line in red that says:

```
symbol boost could not be resolved-> using namespace boost;
```

In the ide and eclipse settings I have the includes have the path home/ubuntu/cpp/boost_1_52_0/
 specified.  Soo..how to I make boost work?  What am I missing?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <time.h>


#include <boost/tokenizer.hpp>
using namespace boost;

using namespace std;
```

Comment: Does it actually say `boot` and not `boost`?

Comment: do you have a typo somewhere? boot?

Comment: fixed typo.  Is is boost

Comment: Is this just an IDE quirk or a compilation error?